# Genre for weird, obscure or underground music

Tags: identify-this-genre, style

I'm looking for obscure music. If anyone knows about an underground artist, or genre, I would be pleased to have your help. I'll take anything from any year or century, as long as it is complex or weird (creative).

Comment: Could you be specific about what would an objective and then an accepted answer?

Comment: @Bebs An accepted answer would be: - An artist or music genre that is unknown by the average listener. - Any type of music; fast or slow, loud or soft, etc. - The music has to be complex or well-composed, like classical music, jazz or progressive rock/metal. I don't want basic or repetitive chords. - It can be old or new.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for "[outsider music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsider_music)". Daniel Johnston, who passed away earlier this week, was perhaps the most famous modern "outsider artist."

> **Outsider music** (from "outsider art") is music created by self-taught or naïve musicians. The term is usually applied to musicians outside the music establishment or who exhibit childlike qualities, and especially those who suffer from intellectual disabilities or mental illnesses. The term was popularized in the 1990s by journalist and WFMU DJ Irwin Chusid.

It can also refer to music that is deliberately outside the mainstream:

- [Party](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iGb-1X7-ME) - Daniel Johnston
- [Fire Extinguisher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ww2WehkjuJA) - Howell Dawdy
- [Unremarkable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc1Gwco70Ho) - Marvin the Robot
- [The Most Unwanted Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gPuH1yeZ08) - Komar & Melamid
- [Cindy Electronium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SHJ6CcML80) - Raymond Scott

You might also enjoy [anti-folk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-folk):

> **Anti-folk** (sometimes antifolk or unfolk) is a music genre that arose in the 1980s in reaction to the insularity of the remnants of the 1960s folk music scene. The music tends to sound raw or experimental with the intention to shock and protest. It generally mocks perceived seriousness and pretension in the established mainstream music scene. Artists of the anti-folk genre seem to observe the "rules" of music, but then deliberately break them

- [I'm Fine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBk21r2Slls) - Kimya Dawson
- [Tramp Star](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnvv0sqdAkY) - Brian Piltin

Another deliberately boundary-pushing genre is [experimental jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avant-garde_jazz):

- [Volunteered Slavery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsaxODHI3fA) - Rahsaan Roland Kirk
- [Giant Steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30FTr6G53VU) - John Coltrane

On the classical side, you might enjoy the work of the experimental modernist composers:

- [Knee Play 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iW0rxLP6td0?t=2m) - Philip Glass

Or maybe some surprising funky baroque music:

- [Chamber Sonatas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e39toz6o_8E) - Buxtehude

I often personally find some of the most interesting music to be songs from outside of the Euro-American pop tradition.

- [Cler Achel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lA28Hq4eK3M) - Tinariwen
- [Train Across Ukraine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwR2xwxsRZc) - GoleM
- [Gamelan Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZZTfu4jWcI) - Amadinda Percussion Group

For whatever reason, Brazilian musicians seem to be particularly creative and innovative...

- [Fingers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNaWGsad_qM) - Airto

...particularly the ones associated with the Tropicalia movement.

- [Panis et Circensus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETqMNQw-a9M) - Os Mutantes
- [Elaeu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjqF9uynSbw) - Tom Ze
- [Meiu Lua Inteira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOdvsfpbYxM) - Caetano Veloso
- [Domingo No Parque](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OztuGomczAo) - Gilberto Gil

[Plunderphonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunderphonics) is a new style that creates deliberately surreal sound collages from found sounds:

- [Frontier Psychiatrist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLrnkK2YEcE) - The Avalanches

Of course, there are some well-known artists who have become famous because of their own idiosyncratic or eccentric visions:

- [Mouth's Cradle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwSvmdZ1t_A) - Bjork
- [Clap Hands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krjxyEme5vM) - Tom Waits (Tom's music gets much much weirder than this, but this is one of my personal favorites)
- [Camarillo Brillo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nllWDc8_9lw) - Frank Zappa
- [Frownland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9lpLm7jwQY) - Captain Beefheart
- [Water Fountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbiFcPhccu8) - tUnEyArDs
- [Time Has Come](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKIzbO5Q1nQ) - Chambers Brothers
- [If You Must](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0xDGXotGIE) - Del the Funkee Homosapien
- [Senses Working Overtime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07Fp-omNXCw) - XTC
- [The Whole World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udmTfK6_aM8) - Outkast
- [Superfast Jellyfish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6zPvkP5uVI) - Gorillaz
- [Once in a Lifetime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IsSpAOD6K8) - David Byrne

And even thoroughly mainstream artists sometimes get a little crazy:

- [Zilch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XdT8lnJL38) - Monkees

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for all the information¡ By the way, how do you know all this music? I mean, how do you find it, because I would also like to learn how to find by myself.

Comment: @Musicfan1206 There's no one single source. I've been passionate about all kinds of music my whole life, and I'm always looking for new songs. As I've gotten older, I've gravitated more towards the odder music because I've heard so much of the mainstream stuff. // This really barely scratches the surface --if you give me more of an idea what you gravitate towards, I can give you more.

Comment: This is a well-researched and a good answer. I agree as well, there is a lot more weird music; and it has never been easier to reach the said music, in the information age.

Comment: @ChrisSunami If you can give me more, then that's perfect. I consider myself really open when it comes to music, so you can give me anything from any style. What I care about in music is the complexity. I'm not a big fan of repeated rhythm, melody or harmony. When it comes to vocals, I'm able to appreciate any type of voice as long as there is no autotune. Sounds fake to me.

Comment: @Musicfan1206 - Have you listened to the above list? If so, what do you gravitate to? What sticks out to you?  I'll continue to edit new things in as I think of them.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - From all the genres that you showed me, I liked experimental jazz and anti folk the most.

Comment: @Musicfan1206 Maybe The Shins, Alt-J, Thelonious Monk, Tuung, Ayreon, Palestrina, XTC, Sweet Honey in the Rock, Tom Waits, Rhiannon Giddens, Charlie Parker, Magnetic Fields

Comment: I also edited the main post to add a few more different entries.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Genre for weird, obscure or underground music
>
> I'm looking for obscure music. [...]

I don't think it's *weird*, but I don't know what you would think (what's to be weird in 2019 by the way?).

You might enjoy crust punk. [Here's an example works by the defunct band ICTUS](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_J4fgB_RHs). It's *dark*. Is it *obscure* too?

What's *obscure* music?

Comment: Obscure: not discovered or known about; uncertain.                           Talking about music, it would mean something outside the mainstream or that is not recognized by  most average listeners. Something that would not enter the billboards. Don't get me wrong, I don't care if something is popular. J.S Bach, Pink Floyd and Coldplay are mainstream pretty much, but I wanted to listen to well-written music I may have never listened before. I do think that mainstream music has become more homogeneous and simple, so when I say ''weird'',  I refer to music that is experimental and innovative.

Answer (score 0):

Cybergoth is one strange sub-culture that involves music.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybergoth)

---

Psychedelic trance should be noted, but you can dispute adding this subculture, as it has somewhat entered the mainstream.

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelic_trance)
- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQa9t5Hc1PQ)

[**Warning**: Noisy, disorienting, and harsh sound in the YouTube link directly above.]

---

If you choose to interact with these sub-cultures directly, take the usual pre-cautions. Some of these sub-cultures just have eccentric but harmless folks, while others have varying levels of very real danger.